# C++ How to create base class which creates derived class object, and access private members of base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, derived-class, base-class

Is there any way I can have a `derived class` that access the `private` members of the `base class`, and at the same time be able to create a `derived` object on a `base class` method inside the `base class`?

Something like this:

```
class Derived;

class Base
{
public:
    void func()
    {
        // I want to create the derived obj here
        Derived derived;
        derived.func();
    }
public:
    int mBase = 5;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void func()
    {
        // I need to have access to the private members of Base inside this method
        mBase = 6; 
    }
};
```

The error is the following:

```
Error: derived uses undefined class Derived.
```

How can I do something like this?

Thank you

Comment: `public: int mBase = 5;`, you probably mean `private` according to your question. And in fact you probably want it `protected` to allow inherited class to access it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be able to use the `Derived` class and call member function in it (which includes the constructor and destructor) the *full* definition needs to be available. In this case it isn't in the `Base::func` function.

The solution is simple: Don't define `func` inline, just declare it and then implement (define) it after the `Derived` class have been defined.

Comment: ... And don't forget `inline` if you define it in the header :)

Answer (score 3):

> a derived class that access the private members of the base class

Usually just by writing `protected` instead of `private`. Is there some reason you can't do that?

```
Error: derived uses undefined class Derived.
```

Just *declare* `func` in the base class definition, and only *define* it after the derived class has been defined:

```
class Base {
public:
    void func();
protected:
    int mBase = 5;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void func() {
        mBase = 6; 
    }
};

void Base::func() {
    Derived derived;
    derived.func();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should read about *polymorphism*. What you probably want is make func() virtual:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void func() { /* Base behavior */ } // or pure = 0
    virtual ~Base() = default; // don't forget!
public:
    int mBase = 5;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void func() override
    {
        // Derived behavior
    }
};
```

About accessing `Base::mBase`, you have two options:

- make `mBase` protected
- add a protected setter that you use in Derived to modify it.